# ScreenWakeUp for iPad 1 (iOs 5)

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation

Is there a software like [ScreenWakeUp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.iiizio.screenwakeup) for an old iPad 1? Couldn't find on appstore

**[EDIT]** Jailbreak *is* an option.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find anything like this on the App Store, since…

- It's a service that restarts on boot (Android permission `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`), which isn't possible on iOS without a jailbreak or without exceptions, and is disallowed on the App Store.

  > **2.8** Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected
- It'd run in the background all the time, which can't happen due to iOS restrictions, and is disallowed on the App Store.

  > **2.16** Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.
- It uses the Android permission `DISABLE_KEYGUARD` which doesn't exist on iOS since apps can't bypass or interact with the system in that way.

  > **2.6** Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

<sup>App Store Guidelines available at https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html</sup>

Comment: Fair enough. Jailbreak *is* an option though. Would then be a suggestion?